# Is the composite function f °g identical to f ' ° g where f ' is f restricted to ran(g). Also, in case of correctness, how to prove this result?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Soppose g is from A to B and that f is from B to C.

Define f' as the set of all couples (x,y) such that :

(1) x belongs to ran(g) ( a subset of B)

(2) y = f(x).

Is it correct to say there is no difference ( in extension) between the original composite function : f ° g and the new one : f ' ° g?

In case it is correct, how to prove this result?

It seems almost true by definition, hence the difficulty of proving it.

Comment: Yes, there is no difference. The composition is a map $A → C$ and it doesn’t see whether is had been composed $A → B → C$ or $A → \operatorname{img} f → C$. In fact, it doesn’t know it had been composed at all. It’s just a map $A → C$.

Comment: @k.stm. - In case the composite function is f°g, should we not say : A --> img (g) --> C , f taking as inputs all the images in the function g?

Comment: Sorry, yes, we should say $A → \operatorname{img} g → C$.

Comment: @k.stm.- Thanks!